# Существуют ли средства автоматизации создания операций CRUD в Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!
Существуют ли средства автоматизации создания операций CRUD в Windows Forms? Хотелось бы что-то похожее на средства ASP.NET MVC. Иными словами хотелось бы, указав имя сущности или таблицы БД получить код реализации графического интерфейса операций  CRUD?

Спасибо.