# Существуют ли средства автоматизации создания операций CRUD в Windows Presentation Foundation?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.
Несколько переформулирую, ранее заданный вопрос ([Существуют ли средства автоматизации создания операций CRUD в Windows Forms?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567867/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-crud-%D0%B2-windows-forms)).

Существуют ли средства автоматизации создания операций CRUD в Windows Presentation Foundation? Хотелось бы что-то похожее на средства ASP.NET MVC. Иными словами хотелось бы, указав имя сущности или таблицы БД получить код реализации графического интерфейса операций CRUD?

Неужели для базы, состоящей из офигенного_числа=888.8 :-) таблиц надо для каждой таблицы рисовать минимум 2 формы для реализации операций CRUD?

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать? Редактор базы? Так есть готовые решения, которые явно лучше любой поделки.

Comment: @Monk Если не трудно, назовите, пожалуйста их

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Любые операции с базой данных — это модельные операции. UI-контролы не должны заниматься модельной работой, и не должны привязываться к модели.

Если вам нужно показывать юзеру сырое содержание таблиц, что-то у вас не так. (Ну или вы пишете специальную программу для редактирования таблиц, но это очень специальный случай.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А есть ли в wf или wpf фреймворки аналогичные ASP.NET MVC? Для wf была не поддерживаемая сейчас User Interface Process Application Bloc. А есть ли что-нибудь актуальное?

Comment: @ВладимирМадорин: Есть некоторое множество MVVM-фреймворков (например, Prism и MVVM Light). Это то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Спасибо. А, насчет того, то ли это что мне нужно предстоит разобраться :-). В этой области у меня еще совсем не глубокие знания